# How to find last inserted bookId from table in sqllite database using Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

class database_tasks:
    bookId = 0
    studentId = 0

    def create_connection(self):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('library Management.db')
            return conn
        except Error as e:
            print(e)             

    def insert(self, conn,dbname, name, writer='none'):
        c = conn.cursor()

        if dbname == "Book_database":            
            database_tasks.bookId += 1
            #sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + database_tasks.bookId + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"
            c.execute ("INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(?,?,?)",(database_tasks.bookId, name, writer))
```

The `bookId` always set to 1 whenever new record is inserted. But I want to insert record with bookId  1 greater than the last inserted record.

How do I initialize this bookId class variable to one more than the last inserted record?

Comment: Is this an XY problem where what you really want to do is set bookId to autoincrement in your database?

Comment: You can add Python code directly after the class to set the variable, e.g. `database_tasks.bookId = 42`.

Comment: What do you mean, "stopped last time"? The last time the program ran? You need to store the bookId externally to your program, such as in your database, as hinted by jordanm.

Comment: @chepner It is stored in the db. One just has to find the largest one.

Comment: @jordann yes I want to set bookId to autoincrement

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Before inserting record to your table Book_database, you need to execute this query.                                              SELECT MAX(bookId)  FROM Book_database and assign this value to your variable database_tasks.bookId.  After then, increment it by 1 as you are expecting in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
class database_tasks:
    def __init__(self,bookId=0,studentId=0):
        self.bookId=bookId
        self.studentId=studentId

    def create_connection(self):
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('library Management.db')
            return conn
        except Error as e:
            print(e)             

    def insert(self, conn,dbname, name, writer='none'):
        c = conn.cursor()

        if dbname == "Book_database":            
            self.bookId += 1
            #sql= "INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(" + database_tasks.bookId + "," + name + "," + writer + ")"
            c.execute ("INSERT INTO Book_database VALUES(?,?,?)",(database_tasks.bookId, name, writer))
```

you can  initialize class as:

```
data = database_tasks()
```

or

```
data = database_tasks(bookId=<id>,studentId=<id>)
```

and insert records:

```
data.insert(coon,dbname,name,writer)
```

let me know if this help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You are already declaring bookId as a class variable/ static variable. Getters and setters don't work in python like they do in languages like java. But for a class variable, you wouldn't need a getter and setter method. If you would like to change a class variable, you can access it outside of the class with a call to database_tasks.bookId.

Comment: Please, can you provide the part of the corrected code ?